# How to retrieve all localStorage values

Tags: key, local-storage, key-value-store

I have used `localStorage["key"]` and `key` being different strings to store my values while developing my app.

Now I don't even know what all keys I have used.

Is there a way to retrieve all key's and its values from my file system?

And is there a way to drop the entire `localStorage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage.clear();` worked just right for dropping!

But the other question of knowing and retrieving all key-value pair still remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterator to get all the keys...

```
for (var key in localStorage) {
    console.log(key + ": " + localStorage[key]);
}
```

Per *oneofthelions*, *localStorage.clear()* works to remove all items.

Comment: `@dbaseman` I am getting critical error if I use `key in localStorage` ??

Comment: @oneofthelions sorry, I meant to write **console.log**.  That should work.  Which browser are you testing on?  This works on Chrome.